# Unity3d. Проблема вызова метода у компонента PhotonView

Tags: unity3d

Я использую `Unity3d 2018 + Photon Unity Networking`. У меня какая-то магия происходит с компонентом `PhotonView`

На `GameObject` есть `PhotonView`, я его использую для синхронизации передвижения персонажа. 
Скрипт - https://pastebin.com/FLx0TKYA

На этом же скрипте есть метод `RPC_Throw()`

Когда я вызываю PhotonView.RPC("RPC_Throw") то происходит NullPointerException, будто компонента PhotonView нет, но он есть! Я при помощи него в реальном времени передвигаю персонажа с помощью метода Move(), и в редакторе тоже смотрю что PhotonView есть, переменная НЕ пустая. Скрин - http://joxi.ru/LmG8KwphwBjOl2

Т.е для одного метода `Move()` **PhotonView** существует, а для другого - нет (причем в одном и том же скрипте).
В чем проблема?

Comment: А Вы уверены, что ошибка "NullPointerException" возникает, потому что "якобы" (PhotonView) PV (название переменной взял из скрипта по Вашей ссылке) = NULL?
По-моему, ошибку следует искать в аргументах метода RPC, т.е. `PV.RPC("RPC_Throw", RpcTarget.All);`

Comment: уже разобрался в чем проблема, но проблему я еще решаю. Проблема вот в чем: при нажатии на кнопку метод Throw срабатывает у ВСЕХ игроков, а не у того, кто нажал кнопку

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот в чем: при нажатии на кнопку метод Throw срабатывает у ВСЕХ игроков, а не у того, кто нажал кнопку. Я добавил проверку PhotonView.IsMine и также разобрался со ссылками.